# android gps source code

Tags: android, gps, android-source

I'm working on the android source code. I need to find the network main code and the gps main code. I found the network file I was looking for:

> /Android_Working_Directory/system/netd/client/NetdClient.cpp

But I couldn't find the gps file.
What I need to do is to log any interactions with this features.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

frameworks/base/location/java/android/location